# How to store/stash JavaScript event and reuse it later?

Tags: javascript, events, local-storage, web-storage

From https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/#trigger-m68

```
let deferredPrompt;

window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
  deferredPrompt = e;
});
```

This code is fine, but I want to trigger the stashed event later, in a different place. To perform that, I need to store an event not just in a variable, but somewhere else.

### The question: how can an event be stored with its methods?

I tried Local Storage with serialization/deserialization of an object:

```
> localStorage.setItem('stashed-event', JSON.stringify(e))
>
> JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('stashed-event'))
```

But this approach doesn't work as expected, because it's storing only key-values and losing all event methods.

Comment: If you want to keep the methods you either need to avoid serialisation (which means nothing persistent) or deserialise into a new instance of the original type.

Comment: What do you mean by triggering it later? On a different page?

Comment: @EliottRobson https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NITk4kXMQDw 14:28 - 15:17

Comment: Please *describe* what you want, don't expect us to sit through a video.

Comment: @deceze I specified the timespan 14:28 - 15:17, it's less than 1 minute.

Comment: Just store in localStorage o somewhere else something like the eventName or identifier. Then on the page that you need to execute it, write an executor, and dump the event to execute when the new page loads. (Cons, you have to put the event code somewhere in the code of the new page).

Comment: Removed indexedDB tag. indexedDB is of no use here and not relevant.

Comment: @Josh indexedDB is mentioned in the answer below...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading your question a few times, and the answers another few,

**The question: how can any javascript Object be stored with its methods?**

**The answer: there is no how.**

**However,**

[Josh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2204759/josh) properly [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50519339) you can extract and store all the serializable properties, say data, from your event.

I will just add you **can create an event** with *somehow* **that same data** later anywhere, this new event will have all the methods any [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) has, but by now probably none of use.

Obviously, even serialized in your data, properties like [timeStamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/timeStamp), [isTrusted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted), etc... will be overriden at creating the new event.

What you just miss / need is an [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/EventTarget), the value of the **event.target** property,
the **reference** which is lost forever when document.body unloads forever, or when serializing the event Object.

But if it is still alive, or if you know what event.target should be, like a DOM Element or any Object **you can reference**, from wherever you recreate the event (where?), just dispatch your event to that object, if it listens to that [event.type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/type),
your brand new event should be at least heard.

**Simple example from MDN** [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/EventTarget), or see [EventTarget.dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)

As a comment over the [extensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50614442) by [cegfault](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1010175/cegfault): **eval**, and text source code... could be **<script>** text source code **</script>**... should your script produces a (String) script. If not you ´d probably better go further backwards to where did your script creates the unserializable things that appear in your event, and think about recreating those things, not the event.

Comment: I wasn't sure which answer I should accept - this one or the answer by Josh or the answer by cegfault - all of them are correct and well-explained. This one was the easiest for me to understand, thanks a lot @lucchi!

Answer (score 9):

You cannot store an event in this manner. You want to store an object. Only serializable properties are storable for such an object. Functions are not serializable in JavaScript. Functions are not serializable in many languages.

Fundamentally this is basically because when you deserialize an object, its signature can change. If you have ever programmed in java, this is similar to a deserialization error when reading in a serialized object and attempting to reconstruct an object. Because the body of a method function of an object can change in between the time the object is written to some storage and then later read, methods are not serializable. This is because when you serialize an object, it does not serialize its interface definition where methods are defined. It just stores data.

Same reason when you serialize to a json string, it drops the functions.

Instead of storing an event, store the useful information from the event in an object (or let things be implicitly dropped by stringify and use the event directly).

Which method of storage you use just depends on things not mentioned in your question. Such as how long it should be stored, whether it should be available outside of your site's origin, how much data will typically be stored, whether there is more than one object to store, etc. Based on the limited information provided in your question, you are probably fine just using either localStorage or an in memory array.

If you find the need to store hundreds of objects then indexedDB would begin to be more appropriate. But just choosing a different storage medium will have no effect whatsoever on whether you can store functions. You cannot store functions.

Comment: Many thanks @Josh for your answer, it is helpful. But I liked lucchi's answer a bit more because it has TL;DR and links :)

Answer (score 8):

There have been loads of talk around this as soon as I/O 2018 mentioned about handling of A2HS event being developer driven from now onwards. This is also captured in the [official doc](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/) and inspired from it, there is a [beautiful article](https://love2dev.com/blog/beforeinstallprompt/) explaining thoroughly how to achieve exactly this scenario. While I'd suggest to go through the complete article for proper understanding of the updated dynamics around the A2HS flow, feel free to jump onto the "The New Add To Homescreen Flow" section for your requirement.

In a nutshell, follow the following steps:

1. Create a variable outside the scope of the `beforeinstallprompt` event handler.
2. Save a reference to the `beforeinstallprompt` event object in the above handler.
3. Use this later to trigger the add to homescreen prompt on demand.

The article have the complete code snippets which you can refer/reuse.

**Edit**: I read your question once again and realized one important aspect you might be specifically looking for, viz., using it "somewhere else". If this means you are referring to using it on a different page, then my suggestion would be to go for storing the event object in:

1. IndexedDB which is a collection of "object stores" which you can just drop objects into. **Disadvantage** - Can have browser compatibility restrictions. Also, can result in large amount of nested callbacks.
2. Or you can choose to use the "in process cache" (heap memory of your application) which doesn't require serializing either. **Disadvantage** - This cannot be shared across multiple servers though.

Other than this, I cannot foresee a con free solution at the moment. But will try to figure it out and possibly update the thread.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on "in process cache"? What is that? How can I google how to use it?

Comment: Hi @LimonMonte , for in process cache, you can try using something as simple as a Map ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map ). You can also explore the immutable-js (https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/).

Comment: This answer is incorrect, I downvoted it. It's the current most upvoted because it was the first one.

Comment: @LimonMonte - Glad you got the things working through other recommendations.
Regarding your last comment though - "The answer is incorrect" : There's nothing incorrect as such here.. Maybe saying "Found a better recommendation" would have been the right way to put it.. :)
"It's the current most upvoted because it was the first one." - Didn't know people upvote answers based on the timestamp. Guess other users/experts must have found some values insights in this answer and hence would have upvoted. At least that what I do.
Never mind, cheers to the fact you got your work going. All the best!

Comment: You suggested "storing the event object in IndexedDB" which was misleading, I wasted some time until I realized that the storage type doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: Well, I don't want to get into the argument of right and wrong. All I can say is it wasn't misleading as your main ask was how to store an event (object) without losing it's methods (or without serializing/deserializing it), that's why I suggested to go for Indexed DB - https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-indexeddb#working_with_object_stores , which can be used for storing objects. At least respect the contribution/efforts, if not appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR to accomplish what you are doing, you have three options:

1. Store a *reference* to the event in a global value (which is what most tutorials - like your referenced youtube video - will recommend you do). This requires the event to run in the same context (ie web page) as when you store the reference
2. When you store the *reference* to the event in localStorage (such as by name or a key/value look up), on the page/context where you want to execute the event, make sure the appropriate functions and libraries are loaded *before* executing the event
3. [strongly NOT recommended] Store the javascript source code in your storate and eval() it later [again, please don't do this]

As mentioned by @Josh and @SaurabhRajpal, what you are asking for, strictly speaking, is not possible in JavaScript. What you are doing with `JSON.stringify(e)` will probably return `undefined` or `null`, as the [MDN documentation for JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) says:

> If undefined, a Function, or a Symbol is encountered during conversion it is either omitted (when it is found in an object) or censored to null (when it is found in an array). JSON.stringify can also just return undefined when passing in "pure" values like JSON.stringify(function(){}) or JSON.stringify(undefined).

In short, **there is no way to store a single function into localStorage (or any other offline storage)**.  To explain why this is not possible, see this example:

```
function foo() {
    console.log("a")
}

function bar() {
    return foo()
}
```

How can you store `bar()` for later usage?  In order to store bar, you would *also* have to store `foo()`.  This becomes much more complicated when you consider referencing a function which is in, or uses, a large library (like jQuery, underscore, D3, charting libraries, etc).  Keep in mind **your computer has already parsed the source code down into binary**, and as such won't easily know how to read the function for every possible if, for, and switch statements to ensure all possible correlated functions and libraries are saved.

If you *really* wanted to do this, you would have to write your own javascript parser, and you *really* don't want to do that!

So what are your options?  First, do everything on the same page, and store the reference to the event in a global value (the youtube video you link to in a comment is using this method).

Your second option is to use a *reference* to the event (not the event itself), and make sure the source code for that reference is use later.  For (html) example:

```
// on page #1
<script src="path/to/my/js/library.js"></script>
...
<script>
    window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        localStorage.setItem('stashed-event', 'before-install')
    })
</script>

// later, on page #2:
<script src="path/to/my/js/library.js"></script>
...
<script>
    var evt = localStorage.setItem('stashed-event', 'before-install')
    if(evt == 'before-install') {
        dosomething() // which would be a function in path/to/my/js/library.js
    }
    // another option here would be to define window listeners for all possible events
    // in your library.js file, and then simply build and trigger the event here. for
    // more about this, see: this link:
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events
</script>
```

Finally, you *can* store javascript source code and then eval() it later.  Please, please, please do NOT do this.  It's bad practice and can lead to very evil things.  But, if you insist:

```
// on page #1
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    SomeAjaxFunction("path/to/my/js/library.js", function(responseText) {
        localStorage.setItem('stashed-event', {
            name: 'before-install',
            call: 'beforeInstallFunction()',
            src:  responseText
        })
    })
})

// later, on page #2:
var evt = localStorage.setItem('stashed-event', 'before-install')
if(evt) {
    console.log("triggering event " + evt.name)
    eval(evt.src)
    eval(evt.call)
}
```

Like I said, this is a really bad idea, but it's an option.

IMHO, I think you're trying to avoid including a library or source code in a later page/app/whatever, and javascript just does not work this way.  It's best to pass around references in-memory, and only use key/value storage for names.  Everything else is a type of coding gymnastics to avoid simply including your source code in the places it needs ot be included.

Comment: Many thanks @cegfault for your answer, it is helpful. I was in doubt which one to accept - yours or lucchi's. I accepted the lucchi's answer probably because I like short answers with references :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a global constant and update it when ever event changes rather than serializing it and de-serializing which is a costly processes. SO this is how you can do it - You can create a window instance and clone the event in the window object so that it wont mutate.(Note this wont won't work across tabs)

```js
window.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.deferredPrompt = Object.assign(e);//Don't mutate
});

let someOtherMethod = ()=>{
  console.log(window.deferredPrompt)
}

window.setInterval(someOtherMethod, 5000);
```

Try clicking after 5 seconds in the last window and check after 5 seconds

Comment: In JavaScript, any global variable is actually a property of the window object. Using one is equivalent to (and interchangeable with) using the other. Moreover, this will just persist for the same page. As soon as the user will move to the other page, this event will be lost. You could use the window.name to persist the information but it just stores string values, thereby defeating the purpose here. Moreover, it also only works as long as the same window/tab is used.

Comment: Thanks saurabh .. Haven't i mentioned those already as precaution in the answer.

Comment: Further do we have any other way other than localStorage (which stores as string) to communicate across tabs. The best way is to make an API which persist the event and fetches on application launch in new tab which is always a choise.

Comment: To your first point, you did mention about it not working across tabs.. what I added was that it won't even work in the same tab if the user navigates to other links from within the page.. like clicking on page B hyperlink from page A.. Now to the 2nd point, there's no other way which I know of.. having an API and storing it in your back-end is always an option, but that's not what he wants.. moreover, again you'll need to serialise / deserealise again while storing/retrieving from back end..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple but successful solution.

The idea is to capture the event in a variable and only fire it when signaled by another window of the same origin (domain etc).

The solution uses localStorage methods as the signaling semaphore.

Here is the code I used. I have tested it successfully in Chrome, both mobile & desktop.

//In event handling window

//Register the ServiceWorker

```
if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js');
};
```

//Capture beforeInstall event

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  window.deferredPrompt = event;
  return false;
})
```

//Wait for signal

```
window.onstorage = event => {
  if (event.key === 'installprompt') {
    //Fire the event when signaled.
    window.deferredPrompt.prompt();
    // Discard event
    window.deferredPrompt = null;
    //Discard storage item
    localStorage.removeItem('installprompt');
  } 
}
```

//In a different window or tab from the same origin fire the event when ready.

```
localStorage.setItem('installprompt', 'whatever');
```

Answer (score -2):

Please see if this helps.

Defining an event listener for 'beforeinstallprompt' event

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  //do all the stufff
  console.log('Event triggered');
});
```

When you want to dispatch the event manually.
Create a new event variable.

```
var myevent = new Event('beforeinstallprompt');
window.dispatchEvent(myevent);
```

Outputs 'Event triggered' in the console.